# jQuery calculate multiply form input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have question about calculation multiply form fields on event change.
Calaculation for new form fields form modila works fine. I have on each form field event if img-X is clicked the form field must be erased, and all fields must be calculated again for new result after that field is deleted.
The problem is in my `<tr></tr>` tags insade table, i have text with class **pdv**, and that field must be calculated with sum of two values **kolicina * cijena**, I mean calculation of three fields give result for output.
Better explanation I will provide with code below, and will explain in details.

## html

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="opa">
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Penkala za ured</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Napomena"/>
        </td>
        <td>Komad</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control kolicina" placeholder=" Količina" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control cijena" placeholder=" Cjena"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control popust" placeholder=" Popust"/>
        </td>
        <td class="pdv">13%</td>
        <td>10.00</td>
        <td>
            <img class="img-responsive remove_element" src="../images/forms/icon_delete.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="opa">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Čokolada</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Napomena"/>
        </td>
        <td>Komad</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control kolicina" placeholder=" Količina"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control cijena" placeholder=" Cjena"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control popust" placeholder=" Popust"/>
        </td>
        <td class="pdv">25%</td>
        <td>5.30</td>
        <td>
            <img class="img-responsive remove_element" src="../images/forms/icon_delete.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="opa">
        <td>52</td>
        <td>Pranje auta</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Napomena"/>
        </td>
        <td>Komad</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control kolicina" placeholder=" Količina"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control cijena" placeholder=" Cjena"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control popust" placeholder=" Popust"/>
        </td>
        <td class="pdv">25%</td>
        <td>6.40</td>
        <td>
            <img class="img-responsive remove_element" src="../forms/icon_delete.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my table with results, you can see class `kolicina - cijena - popust - pdv`, that is all for calculation of form fields. The question is how to take current text from class **pdv** and calculate with **kolicina - cijena - popust**, then after calculation append to some element in html.

In jQuery I have acomplished calculation of fields **kolicina - cijena - popust**, and append them to HTML elemnet. The problem is when pdv text value is 25 or 13 or 5 calculation must go into separated html element.

## html

```
<span><a class="sum">0 </a></span>
<span><a class="popust_count">0 </a></span>
<span><a class="popust_all">0 </a></span>
<span><a class="sum">0 </a></span>
<span>PDV 25%: <a class ="pdv_25">0 </a> | PDV 13%: <a class="pdv_13">0 </a> | PDV 5%: <a class="pdv_5">0 </a></span>
```

And my jQuery code looks like: This code works.

```
$(".prod_go input").keyup(multInputs);

                    $(".remove_element").click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                        multInputs();
                    });

                       function multInputs() {
                           var mult = 0;
                           var sa_popust_uk = 0;

                           var pdv_25 = 0;
                           var pdv_13 = 0;
                           var pdv_5 = 0;
                           // for each row:
                           $("tr.opa").each(function () {
                               // get the values from this row:

                               var $kolicina = $('.kolicina', this).val();
                               var $cijena =   $('.cijena', this).val();
                               var $popust =   $('.popust', this).val();

                               var $total = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1);
                               var $total_popus = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1) * (($popust * 1)/100);

                                /*Porez*/



                               var value1 =Number($(this).closest('tr.opa').find('td[class=pdv]').text().replace(/[%]/g, ""));

                               if (value1 === 25){

                                    var kaos = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1) * (0.25 * 1);
                                    pdv_25 +=kaos;
                               }
                               if (value1 === 13){

                                    var kaos = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1) * (0.13 * 1);
                                    pdv_13 +=kaos;
                               }
                               if (value1 === 5){

                                    var kaos = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1) * (0.05 * 1);
                                    pdv_5 +=kaos;
                               }


                               // set total for the row
                               //$('.sum').text($total);
                               mult += $total;
                               sa_popust_uk += $total_popus;

                           });
                            $(".popust_all").text(mult-sa_popust_uk.toFixed(2)+' kn');
                            $('.sum').text(mult.toFixed(2)+' kn');
                            $('.popust_count').text(sa_popust_uk.toFixed(2)+' kn');

                           /*Append PDV to page*/
                            $('.pdv_25').text(pdv_25.toFixed(2)+' kn');
                            $('.pdv_13').text(pdv_13.toFixed(2)+' kn');
                            $('.pdv_5').text(pdv_5.toFixed(2)+' kn');

                           $('.sum_od_all').text((mult+pdv_25+pdv_13+pdv_5).toFixed(2)+' kn');

                           console.log('PDV 25:'+ pdv_25+' PDV 13:'+ pdv_13+' PDV 5:'+ pdv_5);

                           //$(".sum_od_all").text(mult);
                       }


            });
```

If you can have a look and give me some advice on this form calculation.

Comment: I have replaced that now correctly. @Roko C. Buljan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't fully understood(first of all what you need to put inside the span values), so this is what I get: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hh9012x8/1/)

```
$(".prod_go").on('input','input',multInputs);

function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    var sa_popust_uk = 0;

    $("tr.opa").each(function () {
        var $kolicina = $('.kolicina', this).val(),
            $cijena = $('.cijena', this).val(),
            $popust = $('.popust', this).val(),
            $total = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1),
            $total_popus = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1) * (($popust * 1) / 100);

        //Forge the class name of the span: <td class="pdv">25%</td> becomes pdv_25
        var $pdv_span = 'pdv_'+($('.pdv', this).text().replace('%','')).trim();
        console.log($pdv_span);

        mult += $total;
        sa_popust_uk += $total_popus;
        //Append value to the relative span value
        $('.'+$pdv_span).text(mult);
    });
    $(".popust_all").text(mult - sa_popust_uk.toFixed(2) + ' kn');
    $('.sum').text(mult.toFixed(2) + ' kn');
    $('.popust_count').text(sa_popust_uk.toFixed(2) + ' kn');

}
```

Where `prod_go` is the table class, also I have change `$(".prod_go input").keyup(multInputs);` to `$(".prod_go").on('input','input',multInputs);` since it is more reliable as event.
If you need to distinguish between the multi, then: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hh9012x8/2/)

```
    $(".prod_go").on('input', 'input', multInputs);

function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0,
        mult5 = 0,
        mult13 = 0,
        mult25 = 0,
        sa_popust_uk = 0;

    $("tr.opa").each(function () {
        var $kolicina = $('.kolicina', this).val(),
            $cijena = $('.cijena', this).val(),
            $popust = $('.popust', this).val(),
            $total = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1),
            $total_popus = ($kolicina * 1) * ($cijena * 1) * (($popust * 1) / 100);

        //Forge the class name of the span: <td class="pdv">25%</td> becomes pdv_25
        var $pdv_span = ($('.pdv', this).text().replace('%', '')).trim();
        console.log($pdv_span);
        switch ($pdv_span) {
            case '5':
                mult5 += $total;
                $('.pdv_' + $pdv_span).text(mult5);
                break;
            case '13':
                mult13 += $total;
                $('.pdv_' + $pdv_span).text(mult13);
                break;
            case '25':
                mult25 += $total;
                $('.pdv_' + $pdv_span).text(mult25);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        sa_popust_uk += $total_popus;
    });
    mult = mult5 + mult13 + mult25;
    $(".popust_all").text(mult - sa_popust_uk.toFixed(2) + ' kn');
    $('.sum').text(mult.toFixed(2) + ' kn');
    $('.popust_count').text(sa_popust_uk.toFixed(2) + ' kn');

}
```

Comment: Thak you for your time, I have solved this and i will update my code. Than you @Razorphyn